# Effect of variability due during motor skill training

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, motor

When training fine motor skills, are identically setup practice sessions ideal or, like machine learning, does adding noise/variability to the practice session increase skill acquisition?

Comment: This question might be more educational to people if you included a reference (or link to more detailed discussion) of the ML observation that is the basis for this.

Comment: That's an interesting note +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to "[Motor Skills Are Strengthened through Reconsolidation](http://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(15)01514-6)" (available through SciHub) adding variability to practice sessions increases learning speed. In the paper, patients were directed to move a cursor on a screen to certain targets via pinch force. Patients who's pinch force mapping was modified during each trial ended up learning faster and performing better on the original pinch task.